# Deleting a subdocument in mongo not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Node/Express app where I am trying to delete an embedded subdocument with the $unset operator in a findAndUpdate function. But nothing seems to be happening. I know the filter is correct.

Here is an example of the object, where the embedded subdocument I'm trying to clear is the "shared" object.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6cf8341666b48b847ab956"),
    "emails" : {
        "email_type" : "home",
        "email_address" : "tom@jones.com",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b6cf834ee47267affac2c89")
    },
    "owner_id" : "5b6b2ee79076c830f01145c1",
    "__v" : 0,
    "first_name" : "Tom",
    "last_name" : "Jones",
    "initial" : "",
    "accepted" : true,
    "shared" : {
        "emails" : [
            {
                "email_type" : "personal",
                "email_address" : "randy@pits.com",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b6b2f419076c830f01145c5")
            }
        ],
        "phones" : [
            {
                "phone_number" : "2065567876",
                "phone_type" : "home",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b6b2f289076c830f01145c3")
            },
            {
                "phone_number" : "4256788765",
                "phone_type" : "mobile",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b6b2f399076c830f01145c4")
            }
        ],
        "addresses" : [
            {
                "address" : "19889 West Palm",
                "city" : "Seattle",
                "state" : "State",
                "zip" : "98999",
                "address_type" : "personal",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b6b2f5b9076c830f01145c6")
            }
        ],
        "businesses" : [ ],
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b6cf834ee47267affac2c88"),
        "invite_id" : "TomJones5b6b2ee79076c830f01145c1",
        "first_name" : "Randy",
        "last_name" : "pits"
    },
    "share_id" : "5b6cf834ee47267affac2c8b"
}
```

and here is my function:

```
    const shareId = contact.share_id;

    Contact.findOneAndUpdate({_id:shareId},{
      $unset:{
        "shared":""
      }
    })
```

Not sure what I could be doing wrong...

Update: Thought I'd share the whole block. I've tried all the suggestions, but it just doesn't work.

I don't get what I'm missing:

```
router.route('/deletecontact/:contactId')

.delete(function(req, res) {
    Contact.findOne({ _id: req.params.contactId }, function(err, contact) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        const shareId = contact.share_id;
        console.log('Contact ID is: ' + contact._id);
        console.log('Contact share ID is: ' + shareId);

        // Contact.findOne({_id:shareId}, (err, sender) => {
        //     console.log('The Sender: ', sender);
        // })

        Contact.update({_id:shareId}, {$unset:{shared:1}});


        res.json({ 'msg': 'Successfully removed contact' });

    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: try `$unset:{ shared:1 }`

Comment: @Akrion, Thanks but that didn't work.

Comment: your code is working for me.... Try with hardcoded `shareId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `update` since it would only change one doc anyway.

This mongoDB query works (tested it):

```
db.getCollection('<TEST-COL>').update({
  _id: ObjectId('<YOUR-OBJ-ID')
}, {
  $unset: {
    shared: 1
  }
})
```

Now although that works in Robo 3T and MongoDB console it seems that Mongoose would like you to do something like this:

```
Contact.findOne({'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('<YOURID>')}, function(err, model){
  model.set('shared', undefined)
  model.save()
})
```

[Now as per their docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) this seems to be the overall recommended way due to:

> Also note: although values are casted to their appropriate types when
>   using update, the following are not applied: **defaults, setters, validators, middleware triggered on save**

Comment: Just added the end-point in full in the original post. I've tried all the suggestions, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer for mongoose specifically. Let me know if this works